# "Upload a new picture" button. Quite misleading

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, profile-picture

When I heard of the new method of uploading my picture, I immediately tried it. What I remember is that I clicked the "Change picture" link that slides up when I hover my account picture, then clicked the "Upload new picture" button, indicated the picture's link, and... presto! Profile pic changed (except after that, some complications happened, well...).

And now I've decided to upload *another* picture. I've done what I did before, but then, the original "custom-uploaded" picture's gone! I was thinking that I'm uploading a *new* picture (that is, it doesn't replace the original picture), just as the button says so.

[image: Upload new picture button]

Of course there is that "Change your picture" header in the pop-up. But I think, context-wise, it is just referring to *choosing* the picture you want to show (the gravatar or the custom-uploaded).

I believe the button's label is quite misleading.

Comment: 'Upload a different picture' would probably be better if you have one uploaded, I can see how that would be confusing.

Comment: @TimPost I'm considering the context, and I can't think of a more suitable label for the button, "Set custom picture"?

Comment: Eh, 'Change custom picture' sounds reasonable. 'Alter a piece of the Internet' would be more fun but sadly I don't think that would happen.

Comment: How about “Replace Custom Picture”?          //          P.S. While I’ll agree that you cannot discern the full functionality of the button from its label, I don’t believe that one should assume that “new” means “additional.”  For example, consider “New Year’s Day.”  When you have an election, you get a _new_ president (or sheriff, or whatever).  While “I got a new job” is, arguably, ambiguous, most people would say “I got a second job” if that’s what they meant.  Now let’s continue this discussion on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com "English Language and Usage").